# No route matches [GET] "/index" Ruby on Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and i have got this code in my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
```

But in localhost:3000/index it shows me this error

```
No route matches [GET] "/index"
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get 'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'
```

This code will generate a route for  localhost:3000/welcome/index.

```
get 'index' => 'welcome#index'
```

will generate the route you want. See the docs for more details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks it worked!I will accept ur answer in 9 minute:)

Comment: Glad I could help! Hope you're enjoying rails and ruby so far, it's a great community!